# How can i do the http radio stream on android and Blackberry?

Tags: java, android, blackberry, audio, streaming

How can i do the live http radio stream on android and Blackberry? I didn't fine suitable example for live streaming on Android and Blackberry.

Comment: have u tried the bufferedPlayBackDemo sample provided by RIM with JDE and eclipse pligin

Comment: yes I tried. but that's not working for the live radio streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `StreamingPlayer` class, which allows you to play a stream on your BlackBerry using code similar to the following:

```
String url = "http://mystreamingserver.com/001.mp3"; 
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(url);player.start();
```

See: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255

Comment: Yes. Thanking you. This Link as all the information i am looking for.